# CefSharp Получить исходный код страницы C#

Tags: c#, html, браузер, cefsharp

Всем привет я хочу получить исходный код страницы, но CeFSharp открывает мне блокнот на выходе с html...
Подскажите как исправить, чтобы данные заносились только в переменную.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
namespace Rate_Scanner
{
    public partial class FonbetForm : Form
    {
        ChromiumWebBrowser chrome;
        public FonbetForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChromeBrowser();
        }
        private void InitializeChromeBrowser()
        {
            CefSettings cefSettings = new CefSettings();
            Cef.Initialize(cefSettings);
            chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UOyYR72R7Ik");
            chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.Controls.Add(chrome);
        }
        private string FonbetPage()
        {
            chrome.ViewSource();
            var html = "";
            chrome.GetSourceAsync().ContinueWith(taskHtml =>
            {
                 html = taskHtml.Result;
            });
            return html;
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FonbetPage();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не работает, потому что вот это `html = taskHtml.Result;` срабатывает позже, чем вот это `return html;`. А вот это `chrome.ViewSource();` вообще можно убрать.

Тогда получится, что метод отдельный вовсе не нужен, так как в нём была бы всего одна строка.

```cs
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string html = await chrome.GetSourceAsync();
        MessageBox.Show(html);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

[Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123651/discussion-on-answer-by-aepot-cefsharp-----c).